# Preprocess variables only for certain blocks

Tags: blocks

Is it possible preprocess variables only for certain blocks?
I created `mytheme_preprocess_block__aggregator(&$vars)`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The edit you did and the link you pasted there seems to only deal with theme hook suggestions, doesn't it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do it like that (similar to hook_form_alter()).

The best way to do this would be to use $variables['block']->bid to apply modifications only to the blocks you want:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['block']->bid === 'target_block_id') {
    // do something for this block
  } else if ($variables['block']->bid === 'other_target_block_id') {
    // do something else for this other block
  }
}
```

Comment: I looked at Drupal code, and Drupal doesn't looks for `hook_preprocess_block_MODULE()` or `THEME_preprocess_block_MODULE()`. It handle in a particular way the `__` contained in theme function names, when `theme()` is invoked as `theme('links__contextual__node', ...)`, for example.

Comment: Hmm, good to know!

Comment: 'block_id' is usually the machine name of the block correct?

Comment: Please make use of `$variables['block']->bid` and not `$variables['block_id']` as 'block_id' is not unique to that block.

Comment: I think its a little friendlier to conditionally switch on `$variables['block']->delta` if `$variables['block']->module == 'MODULE'`

Answer (score 12):

Just to confirm, in Drupal 8 you can write preprocess functions for specific blocks. For example:

**Drupal 8**

```
mytheme_preprocess_block__system_branding_block(&$vars) {
  // Make changes to the the system branding block
}
```

But you could also use hook_preprocess_block, and the plugin ID:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['plugin_id'] == 'system_branding_block') {
    // Make changes to the the system branding block
  }
}
```

As mentioned by Alex, in Drupal 7 you'll have to stick with HOOK_preprocess_block, and an id check:

**Drupal 7**

```
mytheme_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['block']->bid === 'target_block_id') {
    // make changes to this block
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried it out right now on D8, neither `MYTHEME_preprocess_block__system_branding_block(&$vars)` works nor does `MYTHEME_preprocess_block__page_title_block(&$variables)`.

Comment: `mytheme_preprocess_block__{my_block_machine_name}(&$variables)` does work on D8.3

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 10 (presumably 8 & beyond), you can dig into the `$vars` array to isolate a particular block type/bundle:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$vars){
  $block_content = $vars['elements']['content']['#block_content'];
  if($block_content instanceof \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent) {
    $block_type = $block_content->bundle();
    // Logic here based on a (custom) block type/bundle.
  }
  else{
    /* A variety of system-generated blocks (logo, menu, etc.) 
       will have other kinds of info in $vars['elements']['content'] 
       you may be able to key off of.
       Views-generated blocks will also provide details 
       about the View and display in $vars['elements']['content'].
    */
  }
}
```