# send variables other than $content and $subject to a custom block template

Tags: 7

I have a custom block defined with Drupal 7 hook_block's, and I need to send a custom variable to the block template that will be set on block_view function, is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preprocess variables only for certain blocks](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/preprocess-variables-only-for-certain-blocks)

Comment: I've done this in the past by manually rendering the block in a parent template via [views_embed_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7). Any params passed in after the second one become vars available to the block tpl.

Comment: On that post they are talking about passing variables from the preprocess hook, I want to know if it's possible to pass them from the block_view hook.

Comment: You can, if you add hook_theme, as well: http://www.paulbooker.co.uk/drupal-developer/tags/hookblockview